# openCV (cv2) module's methods not working, neither auto-completion working in VSCode

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code, pip, deepface

I was working on a Face Recognition project using deepface and openCV (cv2) modules, but methods of cv2 are not working/being recognized by VScode, neither the auto-completion is working. I have installed both these modules from terminal using pip command `pip install opencv-python` and `pip install deepface`.

Moreover,

when i run the script from python's idLE environment, it even shows ModuleNotFoundError for deepface,

while running on VScode, simply exits without doing anything

[image]

For Python IDLE

[image]

I have tried reading many solutions on StackOverFLow and other platform , and most of them say something about path of the modules or selecting a particular interpreter. But I am very confused what to do.

for VSCode, i changed the python interpreter to the Conda one, that resolved the resolving issue of modules for cv2, but auto-completion and methods are still not working

Comment: Have you installed python and pylance extensions in extension sotre? You can use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose the environment so that you may get intellisense and auto-complete. BTW, it seems that you are using code-runner extension to run python file, have you tried use **Run Python File** button?

Comment: sir , I have both pylance and python installed

Comment: Have you check your python interpreter?

Answer (score 1):

You can use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose the environment where the python package has been installed.